# bootstrap autocomplete not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

I have this script -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#typeahead').typeahead({
            source: function (term, process) {
                var url = '@Url.Content("~/Invoice/GetNames")';
                var cname = [];
                return $.getJSON(url, { term: term }, function (data) {

                    $.each(data, function (name, id) {
                        cname.push({ id: id, name: name });
                    });
                    return process(cname);
                });
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

**Autocomplete textbox-**

```
 <input type="text" name="names" value="" id="typeahead" data-provide="typeahead" />
```

I get all things from server side. But the only problem is filtering the data on viewpage.

How do I filter this data, so that it comes in autocomplete.

**Method-**

```
  [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetNames(string term)
        {
            var names = (from u in db.Contacts
                         where u.name.Contains(term)
                         select u).ToArray();
            // A list of names to mimic results from a database
            var results = names.Select(u => new { name = u.name, id = u.Id });

            return new JsonResult()
            {
                Data = results,
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
`<form autocomplete="on">`